# Inner Join without duplicate values SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012, inner-join

I have two tables with these data

table 1 (10 rows)
[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL7Gc.png)

```
MaintRateSplit_ID   MaintChargeItem_ID
86                      256
87                      256
88                      256
89                      256
90                      256
91                      256
92                      256
93                      256
94                      256
95                      256
```

table 2 (10 rows)
[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEEYF.png)

```
MaintChargeItem_ID  Contribution_Maximum_Value
256                       175642.00
256                       33851.00
256                       130888.00
256                       54612.00
256                       66903.00
256                       246747.00
256                       503602.00
256                       85944.00
256                       262130.00
256                       152892.00
```

When I try to join these two tables, i get 100 rows as a result. Is there a solution to get 10 rows only ?

```
SELECT  MaintRateSplit_ID,Contribution_Maximum_Value 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.MaintChargeItem_ID = Table2.MaintChargeItem_ID

This is the desired result 
    MaintRateSplit_ID  Contribution_Maximum_Value
    86                       175642.00
    87                       33851.00
    88                       130888.00
    89                       54612.00
    90                       66903.00
    91                       246747.00
    92                       503602.00
    93                       85944.00
    94                       262130.00
    95                       152892.00
```

Comment: please post your sample data as text,images might be blocked in some domains

Comment: And add your query, it's hard to tell what's wrong with your SQL if it's not included in the question :)

Comment: Your condition is true for every record pair so you get 10 x 10 = 100 rows in your results. What else did you expect? What is the result you *want*  to get?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, can you please see the above desired result

Comment: I did. What makes you combine the value 175642.00 with ID 86? Why not combine it with, say, ID 94 for instance? Is there any rule I don't see?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, yeah i see, you are right  we can not combine these value and there is no rule to depend on it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your query `Table1.MaintChargeItem_ID` and `Table2.MaintChargeItem_ID`  don't seem to be unique columns. They don't hold good for the Foreign Key Constraint. So create `Table2` having a foreign key reference to `Table1`, then try running the query. You may get the result as desired.

```
Create Table1
(MaintRateSplit_ID int NOT NULL, 
MaintChargeItem_ID int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY MaintRateSplit_ID);

Create Table2
(MaintRateSplit_ID int NOT NULL, 
MaintChargeItem_ID int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (MaintRateSplit_ID) REFERENCES Table1(MaintRateSplit_ID));
```

After you have done this, then you can use an `Inner Join` to fetch the desired number of tuples

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.MaintRateSplit_ID=Table2.MaintRateSplit_ID;
```

To understand the foreign key constraint, please go through the link below:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/

To understand the joins, please go through the link below:
https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/